# ROI and Earnings Yield within FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

Can I calculate within FinancialData properties these as follows:

1. Earnings Yield = EBIT/Enterprise value 
   ..where Enterprise value is the sum of market value of equity (including preferred equity) and net interest bearing debt
2. Return of Investment (or Capital) =  EBIT/ Net Fixed Assets + Working Capital

???

Comment: The properties available are given by evaluating `FinancialData["Properties"]`